# Notation for n-array function with domains of different types.

Tags: functions, notation

I'm wondering what notation I should use to express a function R that maps elements from  different sets to either 0 or 1. Is the following a reasonable usage?

$$
R: S_1 \times S_2 \times ... \times S_n \longrightarrow \{0,1\}
$$

Thanks

Comment: Here you denote a function defined on domain of tuples $(s_1,...,s_n)$ where $s_i\in S_i$, and mapping each tuple to $\{0,1\}$. From your question it's not clear if you wanted to achieve exactly that as concept of "elements from different sets" is not precise enough.

Comment: Ok so imagine you have two sets. One is of type "people" with elements "bob" "marie" and "tom" and the other is of type animals and consists of elements "dog" and "cat". The pairing bob and cat should be 1 if bob has a cat and 0 otherwise. Would that be... $$R:People \times Animals \longrightarrow \{0,1\}$$? In which case, how would I notate this for n sets?

Comment: So, you do want Cartesian product of sets. You function will be defined still on same single set, which is the product. Can humans have multiple animals BTW? If yes, then $R: People \times 2^{Animals} \longrightarrow \{0,1\}$ If anything else like furniture there, then $R: People \times 2^{Animals} \times 2^{Furniture} \longrightarrow \{0,1\}$

Comment: In my current problem they can't have multiple animals but that is good to know :). So yes I did want cartesian products of sets in which case my initial notation should be understandable for that purpose.

Comment: In this case you always have people having strictly one animal and strictly one furniture, etc. If you want to express more flexible concept of possessing only subset of available types, then you extend all your non-people $S_i$ by a special "nil" element expressing non-possession and use it in the tuple element, i.e. ("Bob", nil, "chair") means cat-less Bob with a chair

Comment: Awesome thanks for the additional information.